# javascript function not work in IE11

Tags: javascript, php, internet-explorer

This is script working in Google chrome, but not in IE 11, why?:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
var ammount = document.getElementById('ammount');
var price = document.getElementById('price');
var vatrate = document.getElementById('vatrate');
};

function UpdateTotal() {
    var total = parseFloat(price.value) * parseFloat(ammount.value); 
    var totalvat = (parseFloat(price.value) * parseFloat(ammount.value))*(1+(parseFloat(vatrate.value)/100));
    parseFloat(document.getElementById('mezisoucet').value = total);
    parseFloat(document.getElementById('mezisoucetdph').value = totalvat);
};
</script>      



          <form method="post" action="">

          <td><input type="date" name="date" value="2014-02-24"></td>

          <td>
            <input type="text" name="name" value="" autofocus="autofocus">
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="description" value="">
          </td>
          <td><input type="text" name="sku" value="" style="width: 100%;"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="ammount" id="ammount" value="1" onchange="UpdateTotal()" style="width: 100%; text-align: right;"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="mu" value="piece" style="width: 100%; "></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="price" id="price" onchange="UpdateTotal()" value="" style="width: 100%; text-align: right;"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="mezisoucet" id="mezisoucet" readonly="" value="" style="width: 100%; "></td>
          <td>
          <select name="vatrate" id="vatrate" class="selectinput" style="width: 100%;" onchange="UpdateTotal()">
              <option value="21">21 %</option>
              <option value="15">15 %</option>
              <option value="0" selected="">0 %</option>
          </select>
          </td>
          <td><input type="text" name="mezisoucetdph" id="mezisoucetdph" readonly="" value="" style="width: 100%; text-align: right;"></td>
          <td style="padding: 0px; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;">
          <input type="image" src="./img/ico/1385010425_save.png" name="addOrderreceivedwwwItem" value="Save" title="Save">
          </td>
```

In Google Chrome okay, in IE11 debuger error: "Object price is not defined" ..?

Comment: Oh, come on. Help us out a bit. What errors are you getting? Have you tried setting breakpoints to see what's happening?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: At the end of the script you've a `};` too much ;)

Comment: updated error statement in IE11

Comment: understand, i removed php codes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
window.onload = function () {
var ammount = document.getElementById('ammount');
var price = document.getElementById('price');
var vatrate = document.getElementById('vatrate');
};
```

This function declares some variables, and then immediately discards them because they are no longer referenced by anything.

It looks like your intention was to define them as global variables, in which case you should use:

```
window.ammount = document.getElementById('ammount');
// IMPORTANT: Don't use var to declare object properties
```

It should be noted that many browsers will automatically convert element IDs into global variables, which is one reason why having multiple elements with the same ID is a disaster waiting to happen. In your case... I would be very surprised if you only had a single row, and thus all `id`s defined in your PHP there will be duplicated.

Chrome is tolerant of this, using only the first element with a given ID as the automatic global property. IE, however, will set the auto-global property to be a node list containing all such elements, which leads to unexpected results, especially if you then `var` a variable of the same name.

All in all, be more careful with IDs!